# can not set gravity of text view through java code

Tags: android

I am trying to set gravity of the text view through java in the following way

```
if(check.equals("left")){           
        results.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);           
    } else if(check.equals("center")){
        results.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    } else if(check.equals("right")){
        results.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    }
```

But this does not work correctly.
and in XML file the `gravity` is pre-set to `center`.

Here the results is TextView type variable .

this is the parent XML code:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:gravity="center" 
 android:text="Text" android:textSize="30dp" />
```

Please help me

 And whole Layout XML code is

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etCommands"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Type some commands"
    android:inputType="textPassword" >

</EditText>

   <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:weightSum="100"
       >

<Button
    android:onClick="cmdClick"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:id="@+id/bResults"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:text="Try Commond" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/tgPassword"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="80"
    android:checked="true"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:text="ToggleButton"
    android:onClick="togClick"
     />

 </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="Text" 
       android:textSize="30dp"
       />
```

Comment: show us your xml code maybe there is problem in xml

Comment: please post your xml code. the problem may be from your parent layout.
(edit) you didn't even post the problem. what is it you wanted to do, and the result of what you've done so far.

Comment: <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView1"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
           android:gravity="center"
           android:text="Text" 
           android:textSize="30dp"
           />                                                                     this is the parent XML code

Comment: What is `checks` and `results` (i'm assuming thats a TextView but confirm)

Comment: The results variable is just name of variable it not gonna do any thing particular I just wanted to get command from a EditText and set the gravity according to that command (i-e left, center, right etc) that is all about the results variable!! ;-)

Comment: Dear st0le the results is a variable of TextView type and check variable is only for comparing strings (i-e left, center, right etc).

Comment: @Arshay , `equals` is case sensitive, are you entering exactly "left" or "Left"?

Comment: @Arshay, the parent of the Textview ( LinearLayout,RelativeLayout,etc). Is its width set to `fill_parent`?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the layout xml. Also please add the code where the TextView results is instantiated and value for check is assigned.

Comment: @st0le, yes the layout is set  LinearLayout and also its width  is set to "fill_parent"  Whole XML is given above:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a RelativeLayout, and in your TextView XML set 
`android:layout_centerVertical="true"` `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

Depending on your other code, try doing:

```
textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(Layout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL));
```